# Why am I getting uninitialized constant Calabash::ABase (NameError)?

Tags: calabash, calabash-android

I'm using Calabash.  I ran `calabash-android gen` as described [here](https://github.com/calabash/calabash-android). I have a step definition, a page object and a feature.  Here's my page object:

```
class LocationScanPage < Calabash::ABase  
    LIST_BUTTON_QUERY="com.facebook.react.views.text.ReactTextView marked:'List'"

    def trait
        LIST_BUTTON_QUERY
    end

    def await(opts={})
      wait_for_elements_exist([trait])
      self
    end
end
```

When I run `bundle exec calabash-android run .\app-releaseStaging.apk`  I get:

```
uninitialized constant Calabash::ABase (NameError)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `require 'calabash-android'` to the top of the page object fixed it:

```
require 'calabash-android'

class LocationScanPage < Calabash::ABase  
    LIST_BUTTON_QUERY="com.facebook.react.views.text.ReactTextView marked:'List'"

    def trait
        LIST_BUTTON_QUERY
    end

    def await(opts={})
      wait_for_elements_exist([trait])
      self
    end
end
```

`Calabash::ABase` is defined [here](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/calabash-android/Calabash/ABase).